# Why is it impossible to use generic type for variable when instantiating object with concrete type?

Tags: java, generics

```
class A{}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}
class D<C> {
    C c = new A(); // COMPILER ERROR
}
```

After type erasure code becomes:

```
class D {
    Object c = new A();
}
```

So, what's the problem here?

Comment: do you mean `<T super A>` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, what's the problem here?

The first problem is that within `D<C>`, `C` refers to the type parameter called, `C`, *not* the class `C` that extends `B`. Next, even ignoring generics,

```
C c = new A(); // Invalid
```

... wouldn't compile... instead, you'd normally have:

```
A a = new C(); // Normally fine - but not if C is a type parameter!
```

Suppose you tried using:

```
D<String> d = new D<String>();
```

Then you're effectively asking the compiler to consider this line to be valid:

```
String c = new A();
```

That's clearly broken.

Comment: Let me rephrase: why this code doesn't work?
'class A {}
class D<C>{
    C c = new A();
}'

Comment: @AlexeyGalanov: Because `C` might be a type completely different to `A`. It could be `String` for example. The whole point of generics is to introduce more type safety - that doesn't play well if you can declare a variable of type `C` (the type parameter) and initialize it to a reference of some completely different type.

Comment: Because C type could be anything, sorry, stupid question

Comment: Sidenote: Even if OP  was referencing the type `C` within `D<C>`, there would be a problem since `C extends A` (indirectly). Not every `A` is a `C`, but every `C` is an `A`. Therefore, `C c = new A();` will result in a type mismatch.

Comment: @Turing85: Yes, you're right - brain fart! Will edit.